# Banner editable from backend

Tags: php, widgets

Im trying to create a widget area.

Ive added this to the theme.

```
<?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('myWidgetName') ) : else : endif; ?>
```

And then i register the area with

```
   function arphabet_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'myWidgetName',
        'id' => 'home_right_1',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'arphabet_widgets_init' );
```

And it seems to work. I can see my widget area in the panel and i can drag widgets there. 
What i am actually trying to do is to create an area where the webmaster can display HTML tex, and another area that displays an image and the webmaster chooses what image that is displayed in that area.

Som from the backend i would like there to be an HTML editor for the first widget area, and just a image picker for the second. Is there perhaps an easier solution than programming it all myself?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there perhaps an easier solution than programming it all myself?

Download the **Black Studio TinyMCE Widget** plugin from http://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/.

Activate the plugin and drag and drop the **Black Studio TinyMCE** widget in your desired sidebar.

Works great and tested with Wordpress 3.6.1.

[image]

Picture taken from the [plugin's screenshots](http://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/screenshots/).

Comment: Thanks. It will work! Is there something similar that just displays an image?

Comment: Yea, try this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/. Please upvote my above comment if it helped you.